# finding sum of of squares using pipe

Tags: r, pipe

If `x <- 1:5` then the following:

```
sum(x^2)
```

returns 55, the correct answer. However, if the pipe operator is used:

```
x %>% sum(.^2)
```

then this returns 70 (which happens to be the sum of `x^2` and the sum of `x`).

Although there are some ways around this, I mainly would like to know what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question!

What's going on is that the pipe *automatically passes its argument as the first argument* to the following expression, so `x %>% sum(.^2)` is equivalent to `sum(x, x^2)`.

I'm more used to working with `%>%` in a data-frame/tidyverse context, where the first argument to each of the tidyverse verbs (e.g. `mutate`, `filter`, `select`) is itself a data frame:

```
data.frame(x) %>% dplyr::mutate(y=sum(x^2))
```

Comment: I too usually use this in context, however when starting from a data frame, I was using `pull` to select a column and then summing, so instead I just boiled this down to its essence.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
x %>%
.^2 %>%
 sum()

[1] 55
```

It works as the `sum()` line takes the output of the previous line (`.^2`) as it input. On the other hand, in your original approach, the `sum()` line takes as its input, both, the original vector and the power of it and sums it together.

Altenatively:

```
x %>%
 {sum(.^2)}
```

Here, by using braces, the content of left-hand side (LHS), which is the original vector in your case, is not being used as the `sum()` function's first argument (as explained by @Ben Bolker).

Comment: Or the synonym from `library(magrittr)`: `x %>% raise_to_power(2) %>% sum`

Answer (score 1):

A more generalizable approach may be to build your own function, then pipe to that.

For example,

```
SqSum <- function(x){
  sum(x^2)
}
x %>% SqSum()
```

We can now use the same framework to do whatever operations we want.

Also note we avoid many errors that would go unnoticed. For example, using `x %>% SqSum(.x)` will return an error, as we only specified one argument for our function. This **defensive** style programming can be useful.

As for explanation, Ben nailed it...